# Node.js host on OpenShift keeps "Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

I am trying out to host a node.js project on Openshift, here is my `package.json`:

```html
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.13.3",
"formidable": "^1.0.17"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "node index.js"
},
...
```

and here is my `index.js`

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1");


app.get('/', function(req,res){
 res.send("Hello World");
});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port') ,app.get('ip'), function () {
    console.log("✔ Express server listening at %s:%d ", app.get('ip'),app.get('port'));
    server();
});
```

What am I missing and how can I successfully see the expected "Hello World" message? Thanks!

Comment: Note that OpenShift Online is currently undergoing maintenance. Here is the status: http://status.openshift.com/ I would continue troubleshooting after the maintenance is over.

Comment: @Thanks!! Very new to all of these things and do not even know they announce it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your could, and I bet `“Service Temporarily Unavailable”` means exactly that, in this case. Simply try again later after the scheduled maintenance.

Also, check the scheduled maintenances at http://status.openshift.com/ or @openshift_ops

Comment: Thanks Goncalves and Fiala, after the maintenance, it all works as expected!